# Iterating through simplexml objects and appending them

Tags: php, simplexml

I apologize if this has been answered. I've been looking for a solution and couldn't find anything. But I'm trying to iterate through a simplexml that I get out of an API call. The API isn't the best so when the date crosses midnight it's cutting those orders out completely. So to get around it I have to get the orders for the following day as well and then do a foreach on the orders, then I do an if on the date to get the target date. On each loop I want it to take the simplexml objects and put it in a variable and append each new one so by the end I have a new object with only the correct dates.

I tried removing specific nodes, but that seems to be much more convoluted than just combining them at the end of each iteration.

```
if (strtotime($thisFri) >= strtotime($today)) {
    $params = array(
        "shiftStart" => $thisFri . " 00:00:00",
        "shiftEnd" => $thisSat . "12:00:00",
        "status" => "filled"
    );
    $clearConnect->setParameters($params);
    $clearConnect->setResultType('xml');
    $shiftResult = $clearConnect->sendRequest('getOrders'); //gets orders
    $friShifts = simplexml_load_string($shiftResult); //puts the results in to xml
    foreach ($friShifts->order as $shift) { //iterates through each order
        $startLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftStartTime); //figuring out dates
        $start = $startLong->format('Y-m-d');
        $endLong = new DateTime($shift->shiftEndTime);
        $end = $endLong->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($start == $thisFri) { //if to run through all orders with proper start date
```

This is where I'm at. $friShifts is the simplexml which contains a bunch of orders that look like this. Some more happens after this but that's basically what i'm looking for. I want it to put each iteration of the proper date in to a new simplexml to then be run through my other functions.

````
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [orderId] => 3988445
    [status] => filled
    [shiftStartTime] => 2019-01-11T07:00:00
    [shiftEndTime] => 2019-01-11T15:30:00
    [tempId] => 57921
    [firstName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lastName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [clientId] => 1543
    [clientName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [regionName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [orderSpecialty] => School
    [orderCertification] => SLP
    [floor] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [shiftNumber] => 1
    [note] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [payrollNumber] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lessLunchMin] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [dateTimeCreated] => 2018-08-06T17:03:34
    [takenBy] => 480
    [bookedByUserId] => 480
    [orderTypeId] => 1
    [orderType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [city] => Media
    [state] => xx
    [zipCode] => xxxxx
    [orderSourceID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [orderSourceName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [lt_orderID] => 0
    [dateTimeModified] => 2018-08-06T17:03:34
    [subjectID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [subject] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)```
````

Comment: You want to turn it back into an XML string? Why not just keep working with it as objects?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question, I do want it to be a new simplexml object at the end with all of the combined $shift iterations.

Comment: have you tried casting the final object to an array/stdclass?

Comment: I guess my main problem is I can't figure out how to get them to combine. Basically want to have $friDataClean .= $shift or something to that effect after every iteration.

Comment: Can you post XML output of **both** current and next day from *$shiftResult*?

Comment: They're both the same. Getting the following day until 12 just gives me any orders from the current day that cross over midnight. So what I end up with a big list of these objects but some are for, for example, 1/11/2019 and some are 1/12/2019. So I turn those start dates in to dateTime objects and compare it against the day I'm looking for. But to answer the question here is one from 1/12/2019

Comment: (
                    [orderId] => 4178126
                    [status] => filled
                    [shiftStartTime] => 2019-01-12T06:00:00
                    [shiftEndTime] => 2019-01-12T10:00:00
                    [tempId] => 1693958
                    [firstName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (

Comment: I had to cut it up, but it's essentially the same thing